# Add custom tab with dropdown in top header magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'd like to add another tab in the header next to the links **Sign In** and **Create an account**. If the tab is clicked, a dropdown field should appear, In which I can insert other information. Can someone tell me how I can implement this? Thank you in advance!

Edit: I use a custom theme what inherit from the blank theme. I would like to place shipping information in the dropdown box. If the tab is clicked the dropdown box should be opened. There should be no redirection as **Sign In** or **Create an Account**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Please provide more information such as: what theme are you using? where should that "other information" come from or what is it? Did you try anything yet and where exactly do you need help?

Comment: Hi Fabian, i use a custom theme what inherit from the blank theme. I would like to place shipping information in the dropdown box. I don't know whether I should create a modul for this or if I can simply store the information in HTML.

Comment: you can simply store the info using HTML

Answer (score 1):

go to your theme Layout file:
Ex:

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/layout/default.xml

seach for create account link:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
```

under that add the below code:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="help-link" after="register-link-new" >
   <arguments>
      <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customlink</argument>
      <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">contact</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Your costom link will appear after the create account

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the tab is clicked the dropdown box should be opened. There should be no redirection as Sign In or Create an Account